# Java - Socketexception: Connection Reset

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a small chat-program. The 2 classes I have a problem with are the classes containing the clientside and the serverside of a socket. I want the client to read the lines the server sends. I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at MainPanel.run(MainPanel.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I read, that this happens, because the socket connection gets closed on the serverside, but I can't see, where that happens in the code. Can someone explain, why this happens or how to fix it?

Codesnippet from client:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while(true) {
            chatArea.append(br.readLine() + "\n"); //line 121
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Codesnippet from server:

```
while(true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for someone to connect.");
        Socket currentSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Someone connected.");

        sockets.add(currentSocket);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                    while(true) {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(currentSocket.getInputStream()));
                        String input = br.readLine();
                        for(Socket socket : sockets) {
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                            pw.println(input);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    sockets.remove(currentSocket);
                    System.out.println("One connection lost.");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When server application gets terminated, the TCP session which is bound to `Socket` object on the client side throws `SocketException` which is purely normal. There is nothing wrong with your scenario. What you have to do is that you have to handle `SocketException` both on the clientside and the server server side. Either client or server may terminate the TCP session. On the client side you may have a logic that may try to reinitialize the TCP session, whereas on the server side, you clear objects related to the TCP session.

a sample runner class :

```
public class TCPProcessor implements Runnable {
        private Socket s;
        private Thread th;

        public TCPProcessor(Socket s) {
            this.s = s;
            th = new Thread(this);
            tcpProcessors.add(this);
            th.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.trace("socket couldn't be closed");
            }
            th.interrupt();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Request r = null;
            try {
                ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                while (isStarted()) {
                    final Object receivedObject = inFromClient.readObject();
                    // LOGGER.debug("Receiving "
                    // + ((Request) receivedObject).getRequestType() + " "
                    // + receivedObject);
                    r = (Request) receivedObject;
                    processId.set(r.getProcessId());
                    Response rs = new Response();
                    rs.setRequest(r);
                    rs.setServerFrom(GoldenNodeServer.this);
                    if (getOperationBase() != null) {
                        try {
                            Object s = ReflectionUtils.callMethod(getOperationBase(), r.getMethod(), r.getParams());
                            rs.setReturnValue(s);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            rs.setReturnValue(e);
                        }
                        outToClient.writeObject(rs);
                    } else {
                        rs.setReturnValue(new NoClientProxySetException());
                    }
                }
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                // LOGGER.trace("eof occured");
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                if (e.toString().contains("Socket closed") || e.toString().contains("Connection reset")
                        || e.toString().contains("Broken pipe")) {
                } else {
                    stop();
                    LOGGER.error("Error occured" + (r == null ? "" : " while processing " + r) + " ", e.toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                stop();
                LOGGER.error("Error occured" + (r == null ? "" : " while processing " + r) + " ", e.toString());
            } finally {
                tcpProcessors.remove(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hm, I have both applications running at the same time and don't terminate one or the other. On the client side, the TCP session is only initialized, when you click a button, but I only did it once and the error kept occuring, right when the clientside tried to use the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: I realized the wrong logic in your server code. Create a runner class(which implements `Runnable`)  to which you will pass the instance of `Socket` which you get calling `serverSocket.accept()`. Handle each socket in  different threads.

Comment: I attached a sample runner class to my answer. You will also notice how I handle various exceptions that might occur.